# How to delete /var/run/com.cyberghostsrl.CyberghostPrivilegedHelper.socket?

Tags: terminal, finder, unix, macos

how can I delete this file?
if I run `netstat -an` this gets listed

```
/var/run/com.cyberghostsrl.CyberghostPrivilegedHelper.socket
```

it is probably an old installation of cyberghost, but I realy think that this is shady that it is not uninstalled.

I already tried:

```
sudo rm -rf /var/run/com.cyberghostsrl.CyberghostPrivilegedHelper.socket
```

in safeboot mode, but it doesn't get deleted.
What I can see that this only shows up in non safe mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "file" (the name suggests it's actually a socket) is probably getting recreated by cyberghost every time the computer starts up. If you want to get rid of it, you need to *completely* remove cyberghost. I'm not familiar with cyberghost, but it may install some files besides the app itself, that you'll have to track down and remove.

There are some uninstall guides online that're fairly generic, but should give you the info you need to find & remove the relevant files. One thing that might be missing from a generic guide is removing launch daemons and agents: You'll need to look for related files in the folders /Library/LaunchDaemons, /Library/LaunchAgents, and (inside your home folder) ~/Library/LaunchAgents.